# Client not seing the buffer sent by a TCP server in netty

Tags: java, tcp, netty, tcpclient, tcpserver

I have developed in Netty a TCP Server and a TCP client. What I am trying to do is:

- I create the TCP Client and listen to the port
- I create the server
- I listen to the input stream and sends a content to the port

I used the solution proposed by the following StackOverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34705673/unsupportedoperationexception-when-sending-messages-through-serverbootstrap-chan) for the code.

Everything seems to be OK, but the Client does not receive anything. What did I done wrong? To be complete at the beginning my TCP Client was coded in Python, I created a Java client because I did not understand why I did not receive anything, but I have the same problem when my Client is in java (see my complete code below).

The complete code is here:

```
public class TestTCPNetty {
   private ChannelGroup allChannels = null;
   private final int serverPort = 8080;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      TestTCPNetty netty = new TestTCPNetty();
      netty.start();
   }

   private void setupClient() {
      InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(serverPort);
      NioEventLoopGroup clientworkerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
      Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();

      TcpClientHandler handler = new TcpClientHandler();
      bootstrap.group(clientworkerGroup);
      bootstrap.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
      bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
      bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, 500);
      bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.RCVBUF_ALLOCATOR, new FixedRecvByteBufAllocator(500));
      bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 500);
      bootstrap.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
         @Override
         protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
            socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(handler);
         }
      });
      bootstrap.remoteAddress(addr);
      bootstrap.connect();
   }

   private void setupServer() {
      allChannels = new DefaultChannelGroup(GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);

      try {
         EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
         EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
         ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
         b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                 .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                 .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                       ch.pipeline().addLast("MyMessageHandler", new MyMessageHandler());
                       ch.pipeline().addLast("grouper", new GlobalSendHandler());
                    }
                 })
                 .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
                 .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

         // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
         ChannelFuture f = b.bind(serverPort).sync();
         Channel ch = f.channel();
         ByteBufAllocator alloc = ch.alloc();

         System.out.println("Server: Running!");

         // Read commands from the stdin.
         ChannelGroupFuture lastWriteFuture = null;
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         while (true) {
            String line = in.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
               break;
            }

            ByteBuf getOut = alloc.buffer(64);
            getOut.writeBytes(line.getBytes());

            // Sends the received line to the server.
            lastWriteFuture = allChannels.writeAndFlush(getOut);

            lastWriteFuture.addListener(new ChannelGroupFutureListener() {
               @Override
               public void operationComplete(ChannelGroupFuture cf) throws Exception {
                  if (cf.isSuccess()) {
                     System.out.println("CFListener: SUCCESS! YEAH! HELL! YEAH!");
                  } else {
                     System.out.println("CFListener: failure! FAILure! FAILURE!");
                     System.out.println(cf.cause());
                  }
               }
            });

         }

         // Wait until all messages are flushed before closing the channel.
         if (lastWriteFuture != null) {
            lastWriteFuture.sync();
         }

         // Wait until the server socket is closed.
         // In this example, this does not happen, but you can do that to gracefully
         // shut down your server.
         f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }
   }

   public void start() {
      setupClient();
      setupServer();
   }

   public class GlobalSendHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
      @Override
      public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
         allChannels.add(ctx.channel());
         try {
            super.channelActive(ctx);
         } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
   }

   public class MyMessageHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
      @Override
      public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
      }
   }

   public class TcpClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
      @Override
      public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
         ByteBuf buf = (ByteBuf) msg;
         CharSequence sequence = buf.readCharSequence(buf.readableBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
         String str = sequence.toString().trim();
         System.err.println(str);
      }

      @Override
      public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
      }

      @Override
      public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
         ctx.close();
      }
   }
}
```

I took into account the comment from Norman Maurer. In the new code I am performing the Client connection and runtime in another Thread:

```
public class TestTCPNetty {
   private ChannelGroup allChannels = null;
   private final int serverPort = 8080;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      TestTCPNetty netty = new TestTCPNetty();
      netty.start();
   }

   private void setupClient() {
      InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(serverPort);
      NioEventLoopGroup clientworkerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
      Bootstrap bootstrap = new Bootstrap();

      TcpClientHandler handler = new TcpClientHandler();
      bootstrap.group(clientworkerGroup);
      bootstrap.channel(NioSocketChannel.class);
      bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
      bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, 500);
      bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.RCVBUF_ALLOCATOR, new FixedRecvByteBufAllocator(500));
      bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 500);
      bootstrap.handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
         @Override
         protected void initChannel(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws Exception {
            socketChannel.pipeline().addLast(handler);
         }
      });
      bootstrap.remoteAddress(addr);
      try {
         ChannelFuture f = bootstrap.connect().sync();
         System.out.println("Future is  failed ? " + f.isSuccess());
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   private void setupServer() {
      allChannels = new DefaultChannelGroup(GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);

      try {
         EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
         EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
         ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
         b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                 .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                 .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                       ch.pipeline().addLast("MyMessageHandler", new MyMessageHandler());
                       ch.pipeline().addLast("grouper", new GlobalSendHandler());
                    }
                 })
                 .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
                 .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

         // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
         ChannelFuture f = b.bind(serverPort).sync();
         Channel ch = f.channel();
         ByteBufAllocator alloc = ch.alloc();

         System.out.println("Server: Running!");

         // Read commands from the stdin.
         ChannelGroupFuture lastWriteFuture = null;
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         while (true) {
            String line = in.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
               break;
            }

            ByteBuf getOut = alloc.buffer(64);
            getOut.writeBytes(line.getBytes());

            // Sends the received line to the server.
            lastWriteFuture = allChannels.writeAndFlush(getOut);

            lastWriteFuture.addListener(new ChannelGroupFutureListener() {
               @Override
               public void operationComplete(ChannelGroupFuture cf) throws Exception {
                  if (cf.isSuccess()) {
                     System.out.println("CFListener: SUCCESS! YEAH! HELL! YEAH!");
                  } else {
                     System.out.println("CFListener: failure! FAILure! FAILURE!");
                     System.out.println(cf.cause());
                  }
               }
            });

         }

         // Wait until all messages are flushed before closing the channel.
         if (lastWriteFuture != null) {
            lastWriteFuture.sync();
         }

         // Wait until the server socket is closed.
         // In this example, this does not happen, but you can do that to gracefully
         // shut down your server.
         f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }
   }

   public void start() {
      Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            setupClient();
         }
      });
      t1.start();
      setupServer();
   }

   public class GlobalSendHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
      @Override
      public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
         allChannels.add(ctx.channel());
         try {
            super.channelActive(ctx);
         } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
   }

   public class MyMessageHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
      @Override
      public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
      }
   }

   public class TcpClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
      @Override
      public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
         ByteBuf buf = (ByteBuf) msg;
         CharSequence sequence = buf.readCharSequence(buf.readableBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
         String str = sequence.toString().trim();
         System.err.println(str);
      }

      @Override
      public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
      }

      @Override
      public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
         ctx.close();
      }
   }
}
```

Now the Client connection work (I receive the message "Server: Running!" then "Future is  failed ? true"), but the Client still receives nothing.

Comment: Are you sure the future that is returned by `connect(...)` is not failed ?

Comment: You are right, If I am doing:       ChannelFuture f = bootstrap.connect();
      System.out.println("Future is  failed ? " + f.isSuccess()); the boolean is false. Why?

Comment: what happens if you use:  bootstrap.connect().sync() `?

Comment: I get the following exception: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8080

Comment: As explained in the my update, I performed the connection of the Client in another Thread, now the Client connects correctly, but it still receives nothing from the Server

Comment: I am pretty sure you need to use some valid IP address as well when you connect.